# Critique the following "proofs" that an arbitrary constant must be $0$.

Tags: integration, fake-proofs

1) $C=\int 0\, dx$=$\int 0\times0\, dx$=$0\times\int 0\,dx$=$0$. Basically, why can't you factor a zero out of the integral.

2) $0=(\int x\,dx)-(\int x\,dx)=\int(x-x)dx=\int 0\, dx=C$

Comment: More generally, let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be two arbitrary constants. Then $$C_1=\int0dx=C_2$$ proving that all constants are equal.

Comment: Yeah @bof that just makes it worse. I need to know why it's wrong

Comment: It's wrong because a function has infinitely many indefinite integrals, not just one (the arbitrary constant is ***arbitrary***), so you can't equate them to each other and say that, for example, $$\int\cos xdx=\sin x=\sin x+1=\sin x+2=\sin x +3=\sin x+\frac{\pi^2}6=\cdots.$$

Comment: In other words, it's basically the same mistake as $$\frac\pi4=\arctan1=-\frac{3\pi}4.$$

Comment: It's wrong because $\int 0 dx = 0 + C$. Basically, from the other direction $C' = 0$ for all constants $C$.

Comment: It's the math version of the masked man fallacy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that
the notation $\int f$ does not mean any specific function. In fact, it means a *family* of functions. More precisely, the set of all the solutions to the differential equation
$
F'=f.
$
The "identity" 
$$
\int f=F+C\quad \text{for arbitrary constant }C,
$$
is *not* really an identity at all. A more appropriate way to understand it might be
$$
\int f=\{F+C\mid F'=f\text{ and }C\in\mathbb{R}\}.
$$

In the first argument (1), $C$ is a *fixed* number and the expression $C=\int 0\ dx$ can not be thought as an "identity". It means the derivative of $f=C$ is $0$. Otherwise, by
$$
0=\int 0\ dx
$$
and 
$$
2016=\int 0\ dx
$$
one could conclude that $0=2016$.

Comment: What do you mean by "one is losing a constant term"?

Comment: @AaronM: I just edited my answer.