# Why isn't $\ln z = \ln z + 2k\pi\mathrm{i}$ a contradiction?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, logarithms

> Define $$\operatorname{Ln} z = \operatorname{Ln} |z| + \mathrm{i}\operatorname{Arg}(z), \ \ \ \ \ z\in\Bbb{C}\backslash\{0\}, \ \ \ \ \ -\pi< \operatorname{Arg}(z) \leq \pi$$
>   where $\operatorname{Ln}|z|$ is the usual real-valued natural logarithm. Furthermore, we state $$\ln z = \operatorname{Ln} |z| + \mathrm{i}\arg(z) = \operatorname{Ln} |z| + \mathrm{i}\left[\operatorname{Arg} (z) + 2k\pi\right], \ \ \ \ \ k\in\Bbb{Z}.$$ Distributing the imaginary unit $\mathrm{i}$ yields $$\ln z = \operatorname{Ln} z + 2k\pi\mathrm{i}, \ \ \ \ \ k\in \Bbb{Z}.$$ Exponential function is defined as $$\mathrm{e}^z = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n!}.$$

---

From [SCIPP's](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/) notes, in particular [this handout](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph116A/clog_11.pdf) on pages 6$-$7, it is seen that

$$\ln(\mathrm{e}^z) = z + 2k\pi\mathrm{i} \neq z \ \ \ \ \text{unless}\ \  k = 0.\tag1$$

This is in line with the definition as stated above. However, they go on to assert

$$\ln w = \ln w + 2k\pi\mathrm{i}, \ \ \ \ w \in \Bbb{C}\backslash\{0\}.\tag2$$

- Why is $(2)$ not a contradiction?

Assume instead $(2)$ is valid. Then substract $2k\pi\mathrm{i}$ from both sides of $(1)$ and $(2)$:

$$\ln(\mathrm{e}^z) -  2k\pi\mathrm{i} = z\tag{3}$$
$$\ln w - 2k\pi\mathrm{i} = \ln w.\tag{3'}$$

Take $w = e^z$ in $(3')$ and plug the result back into $(3)$. We arrive at

$$\ln(e^z) = z \overset{(1)}{\implies} z \neq z.$$

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Its all multi-valued.  What did you expect was going to happen?  Indeed, the error begins in $(2)$ by the way.

Comment: The use of $\hbox{Ln}$ and $\ln$ is really a mess in the post. I would denote the complex logarithm with $\log$ and the real logarithm with $\ln$. When defining the principal branch of $\log$, one can use $\hbox{Log}$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Glad to see the notes are wrong instead of me for once :). I first noticed the problem in [SCIPP's other handout](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/archives/physics116A10/arc_10.pdf) where they "prove" why the complex $\arctan$ has the form it has.

Comment: @Jack Agreed. I resorted to such because it would be easier to then follow the linked handout. Will keep in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- In the world of real numbers, one always has
  $$
  e^{\ln x}=\ln(e^x)=x
  $$
  for $x>0$. However, one should not expect the same thing happens in the world of complex numbers.
- (2) is not a contradiction by "definition" of the complex logarithm and the sentence "In fact, the latter is completely valid as a
  set equality in light of eq. (43)." in the handout. It is very similar to saying that
  $$
  \int f(x)\ dx=\int f(x)\ dx+C\tag{*}
  $$ 
  which is indeed very confusing! One should really understand (using you notation in the post) $\ln z$ as a *set*, not a complex number. Thus one should avoid doing "cancellation" in (2) just as in (*) one could easily get the [nonsense](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1960059/9464) $0=1$ by doing cancellation (let $C=1$).
- "Where have I gone wrong?"  The identity $\ln(e^z)=z$ and the very last "$\Rightarrow$" sign are incorrect. One needs to be careful that in (1), there is a phrase "unless $k=0$".

Comment: Yeah... [jumped the gun on this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2183941/why-isnt-ln-z-ln-z-2k-pi-mathrmi-a-contradiction?noredirect=1#comment4492516_2183941). Careless on my part. Will do better in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$$\ln w=\ln w+2k\pi i$$ is said nowhere to be an identity (which would make no sense).

Mind the nuances between $\ln z,\ln|z|,\text{Ln } z$ and $\text{Ln }|z|$.

Comment: Page 7 paragraph 2 lines 3$-$4 in the linked handout (the correctness of it is of course another matter).

Comment: @LinearChristmas: read the sentence right after that formula: "In fact, the latter is completely valid as a set equality in light of eq. (43)."

Comment: @LinearChristmas And "This *seems* to imply..."

Comment: @YvesDaoust Haha. Looks like I should have gone to EnglishLearners.SE with this question...